# C++: References to References, Stroustrup Example

Tags: c++, c++11

Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 196 has a section called References to References.  I have included the code.  Does anyone have examples of situations where these references to references would be used?

I'm having a challenging time conceptualizing this.  Thanks

```
using rr_i = int&&;
using lr_i = int&;
using rr_rr_i = rr_i&&; // ‘‘int && &&’’ is an int&&
using lr_rr_i = rr_i&; // ‘‘int && &’’ is an int&
using rr_lr_i = lr_i&&; // ‘‘int & &&’’ is an int&
using lr_lr_i = lr_i&; // ‘‘int & &’’ is an int&
```

> In other words, lvalue reference always wins.

Comment: The only case in which a 'reference to reference' can arise is, notionally, during template argument deduction, in which case it gets reference-collapsed to 'just a reference'. The link explains that. This is extremely useful/important for template deduction, perfect forwarding, etc.

Comment: @und it can also happen when doing `auto&& bar = foo();`. No?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert Sure, but isn't that following the same rules as template argument deduction? Sorry for not being clear; I think of those as one and the same thing, but I appreciate that's not obvious to people who don't already conceptualise it that way.

Comment: @underscore_d regarding that article, it seems one could write an entire book on this topic. Still reading....

Answer (score 1):

They wouldn't be.

The comments show that the "extra" references are dropped. That's a good thing, because otherwise the program would be invalid (as there are no "references to references" in the language).

> [`[dcl.ref]/6`:](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#dcl.ref-6) If a *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or a *decltype-specifier* denotes a type `TR` that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type “lvalue reference to `T`”, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type `TR`. *[ Note:* This rule is known as reference collapsing. *— end note ] [ Example:*
>
> ```
> int i;
> typedef int& LRI;
> typedef int&& RRI;
>
> LRI& r1 = i;                    // r1 has the type int&
> const LRI& r2 = i;              // r2 has the type int&
> const LRI&& r3 = i;             // r3 has the type int&
>
> RRI& r4 = i;                    // r4 has the type int&
> RRI&& r5 = 5;                   // r5 has the type int&&
>
> decltype(r2)& r6 = i;           // r6 has the type int&
> decltype(r2)&& r7 = i;          // r7 has the type int&
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

This is a tool to make template programming easier: you don't have to strip the "redundant" references off yourself. Arguably you wouldn't often encounter the need for this, but in more complex codebases with lots of templates and/or aliases, it can happen.

---

When you have a function template like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& arg)
```

and pass an *lvalue `int`*, then your `arg` will be an `int&`; if you pass an *rvalue `int`*, then it'll be an `int&&`. This is called a "forwarding reference" (or "universal reference"), and is not the same rule as reference collapsing, though it does have similar utility in making life easier for template programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference

```cpp
int i;
int& ii = i;
```

A reference can't be referenced. This is NOT a reference to reference. Both ii and iii are references to i:

```cpp
int i;
int& ii = i;
int& iii = ii;
```

This is an rvalue reference

```cpp
int&& r = 123;
```

This is a nonsense and will fail compilation.

```cpp
int i;
int& ii = i;
int&& nonsense = &ii;//fail compilation
int&& nonsense2  = i;//fail compilation
```

But a pointer can be pointed and referenced

```cpp
int i, j;
int* p = &i;
int** pp = &p;
int*& rp = p;
rp = &j;
```

Comment: `r` is still an lvalue in that example.

Comment: The reason `int&& nonsence = &ii` fails compilation is that you gave it a pointer

Comment: and none of this explains reference collapsing

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings how is r and lvalue?  Is that not a literal and if the literal cannot be an lvalue, it is an rvalue.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings agree, this doesn't not explain ref collapsing.

Comment: @notaorb `123` is an rvalue. `r` is not. It's the name of an `int` object that was created from the rvalue expression (and literal) `123` and lifetime-extended by being bound to a reference.

Comment: Also note that value categories relate to expressions, not to things/objects. It does not make sense to say that any particular object "is" an rvalue or an lvalue. Only expressions can be called that. An example of an expression is `r`, which in this case contains the name of an object and nothing else. But the object itself that is being named has no value category, only a type.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings regarding r and 123.  Is r not an "rvalue" reference.  That is the information I have learned so far in Stroustrup up to this page.  Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @notaorb rvalues and rvalue references are not the same thing. Yes it's confusing. There's a lot of complicated machinery at work here. Your declaration introduces an rvalue reference called `r` that refers to a temporary `int` constructed from the rvalue expression (and literal) `123`. An expression consisting of the symbols `r` is an lvalue expression of type `int` that refers to that `int`. You'd have to write `std::move(r)` to get an rvalue expression referring to it again; indeed, this is why `std::move` exists!

Comment: So is r and rvalue reference and 123 an rvalue?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Move is just static_cast<T&&>(x).  r is already that type.  How would move change anything?

Comment: @notaorb Because of how expressions work. An expression has a type, and it has a value category. Just writing `r` is an lvalue expression of type `int`. Writing `std::move(r)` is an rvalue expression of type `int`. You're only considering types; and you're missing a few things there too: move does return `int&&`, but expressions drop references before further processing.

Comment: (after using them to help determine the value category)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ok, that's an rvalue reference. Thanks for pointing out. I wanted to  show that there is no such thing as reference to reference in C++.